# Toggle between three states with UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIButton` for which I want to switch the title and color when I press it. The button should have three states: daily, monthly and yearly.

Right now I have this solution which doesn't seem that elegant:

```
if sender.currentTitle == "Daily" {
    sender.setTitle("Monthly", for: .normal)
    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor(hex: "FB967F"), for: .normal)
} else if sender.currentTitle == "Monthly" {
    sender.setTitle("Yearly", for: .normal)
    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor(hex: "A395CE"), for: .normal)
} else if sender.currentTitle == "Yearly" {
    sender.setTitle("Daily", for: .normal)
    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor(hex: "75CFF8"), for: .normal)
}
```

Is there a more convenient way to do this in Swift ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a `counter` variable and two arrays

```
var counter = 0
let titleArray = ["Daily", "Monthly", "Yearly"]
let colorArray = ["FB967F", "A395CE", "75CFF8"]
```

then increment the counter (keep it in range 0...2 via the modulo operator) and get the title and color values from the arrays

```
counter = (counter + 1) % titleArray.count
sender.setTitle(titleArray[counter], for: .normal)
sender.setTitleColor(UIColor(hex: colorArray[counter]), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use an enum
It is the best for maintaining states. Keeps your code super clean and readable.

```
enum ButtonState {
    case daily
    case monthly
    case yearly

    mutating func next(forButton button:UIButton) {
        switch (self) {
        case .daily:
            self = .monthly
        case .monthly:
            self = .yearly
        case .yearly:
            self = .daily
        }

        button.setTitle(self.getTitle(), forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor(hex: self.getTitleColorHex()), forState: .Normal)
    }

    private func getTitle() -> String {
        switch (self) {
        case .daily:
            return "Daily"
        case .monthly:
            return "Monthly"
        case .yearly:
            return "Yearly"
        }
    }

    private func getTitleColorHex() -> String {
        switch (self) {
        case .daily:
            return "FB967F"
        case .monthly:
            return "A395CE"
        case .yearly:
            return "75CFF8"
        }
    }
}

var currentButtonState = ButtonState.daily

func changeButtonState(forButton button:UIButton) {
    currentButtonState.next(forButton: button)
}
```

Comment: You've turned 10 lines of code into 40. Is that more readable? :)

Comment: lol. its all about the abstraction, You can choose to create arrays of the two parameters, and just use the rawvalue from the enum to fetch the results, which would reduce it to half
I just wrote it in full to give a clearer idea of whats going on.

Think about the view controller code - which is just 2 lines. ;), and also the ability to abstract and encapsulate the whole state implementation.

Comment: this is a beautiful way to achieve this.... Learned a lot from it thanks!

Comment: This is nice. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really think your code is *so* inelegant - three-states are not so complex that they are difficult to read (which is really the problem with inelegant code), however, if it was more than three you would definitely want something neater. How about using a state-transition dictionary:

```
func newButtonState(sender: UIButton) {
    let buttonDict = ["Yearly": (UIColor.red, "Daily"), 
                      "Monthly": (UIColor.green, "Yearly"), 
                      "Daily": (UIColor.yellow, "Monthly")]
    if let t = sender.currentTitle, let n: (UIColor, String) = buttonDict[t] {
        sender.setTitle(n.1, for: .normal)
        sender.setTitleColor(n.0, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply call the function - the button "state" is its title, and the function cycles through the titles...